# Error with grails output as json

Tags: grails

I got the grails output as json which looks like following output

```
{"code":0,"message":"SUCCESS","packet":{"id":"1","name":"unit1"}}
```

here, i want packet values to be placed in square bracket like following code

```
{"code":0,"message":"SUCCESS","packet":[{"id":"1","name":"unit1"}]}
```

what should i do to get the packets in square bracket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript/JSON `[]` if used for arrays. And `[{}]` is array of objects (you need a one-element array, actually).

So, just pass a one-elemetn list/array, like:

```
def resp = [
  code: 0,
  message: 'SUCCESS',
  packet: [
    [
       id: '1',
       name: 'unit1'
    ]
  ]
render resp as JSON
```